# tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

This is a simple tensorflow code that creates 2 models with shared parameters but different inputs (placeholders).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + [64], name='states')

        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + [64],
                                name='y')
        self.x_test = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + [64],
                                     name='states_test')

        self.is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_training')

        self.model()

    def network(self, x, reuse):
        with tf.variable_scope('test_network', reuse=reuse):
            h1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 64)
            bn1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h1, training=self.is_training)
            drp1 = tf.layers.dropout(tf.nn.relu(bn1), rate=.9, training=self.is_training,
                                     name='dropout')
            h2 = tf.layers.dense(drp1, 64)
            bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h2, training=self.is_training)
            out = tf.layers.dropout(tf.nn.relu(bn2), rate=.9, training=self.is_training,
                                    name='dropout')
            return out

    def model(self):
        self.out = self.network(self.x, False)
        self.out_test = self.network(self.x_test, True)

        self.loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.out, self.y)
        extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
            self.train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(.00002).minimize(self.loss)


def main(_):
    my_test = Test()
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    batch_x = np.zeros((4, 64))
    batch_y = np.zeros((4, 64))
    for i in range(10):
        feed_dict = {my_test.x: batch_x, my_test.y: batch_y, my_test.is_training: True}
        _, loss = sess.run([my_test.train_step, my_test.loss], feed_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

When I run the "train_step" node I get this error:

```
    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'states_test' with dtype float and shape [?,64]
         [[Node: states_test = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
         [[Node: mean_squared_error/value/_77 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2678_mean_squared_error/value", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Although the train_step node isn't connected to the "states_test" placeholder and id doesn't need it to run!, so why should I feed it?

However, if I change the model function so the second network is created after the optimizer, the code runs without any error! (like this):

```
def model(self):
    self.out = self.network(self.x, False)

    self.loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.out, self.y)
    extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
        self.train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(.00002).minimize(self.loss)

    self.out_test = self.network(self.x_test, True)
```

Why is this happening even though the two codes lead to the same tensorflow graph ?
Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of batch norm, namely these lines:

```
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
            self.train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(.00002).minimize(self.loss)
```

Note, that you have two graphs, which share variables - your training and testing graphs. You create both first, and then you create the optimiser. However, you use **control dependencies** on `extra_update_ops`, which is a collection of **all** update ops. The problem is - each batch norm creates update ops (to track the mean/variances) - and you have one in your train graph and one in your **test graph**. Consequently by requesting control dependency you are telling TF that your train ops can execute **if and only if** batch norm statistics in both train **and test graphs** executed. And this requires feeding test samples. So what you should do? Change your extra_update_ops to include only train graph updates (through name scopes, manual filtering or any other method) or call tf.get_collection before constructing the test graph, so:

```
   def model(self):
        self.out = self.network(self.x, False)
        # Note that at this point we only gather train batch_norms
        extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS) 

        self.out_test = self.network(self.x_test, True)

        self.loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.out, self.y)
        with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
            self.train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(.00002).minimize(self.loss)
```

You might want to pass reuse=True to your batchnorms too.